# Unable to install Foundation 6 cli when bower problem

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, bower, zurb-foundation-6

I have installed foundation 6 already on a computer a while ago and worked fine however I am trying on another computer and I get this messages. I am not a code or computer wizard. I would appreciate if someone could help me with what I need to do exactly with this so I can continue working on my website.Thank you in advance. I have git and node.js installed as per zurb foundation 6 installation guide.

Trying to install cli on windows 10 and even try on mac no result does not work. use sublime text 3

```
C:\Users\coco>npm install -g foundation-cli
```

> npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for
>   new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read
>   how to migrate legacy project here:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
>   [..................] - fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We
>   don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and
>   Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11:
>   please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and
>   future versions of Node.js npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This
>   module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do
>   not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
>   C:\Users\coco\AppData\Roaming\npm\foundation ->
>   C:\Users\coco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\bin\foundation.js
>   + foundation-cli@2.2.5 added 323 packages from 529 contributors in 301.497s

```
C:\Users\coco>npm install --global foundation-cli
```

> npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.8: We don't recommend using Bower for
>   new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read
>   how to migrate legacy project here:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ npm WARN
>   deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for
>   compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js npm WARN
>   deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals
>   and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to
>   graceful-fs@4.x. C:\Users\coco\AppData\Roaming\npm\foundation ->
>   C:\Users\coco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\bin\foundation.js
>   + foundation-cli@2.2.5 updated 3 packages in 18.851s

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings, `foundation` should be globally available now.